# 100% Div Height Issue

Tags: css, html, xhtml, height

I have two containers (`main-container` and `sub-container`). Body, HTML and main-container have classes of `100%` height whereas `sub-container` fixed in `1000px`. Main-container should be fit with `100%` height in the whole screen even `sub-container` is small or large. Now problem is, main-container is not increasing its height according to sub-container height. Please check the example below to understand my requirement.

http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/dLeHL/

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

change `height:100%;` to `min-height:100%;` in `.main-container`: http://jsfiddle.net/dLeHL/3/

EDIT:

Percentage heights rules are explained [here](http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/height-and-min-height/):

> Percentage Heights If the height of an element is set to a percentage,
>   it needs for its parent element to have a set height. In other words,
>   the height of the parent element can't be set to auto. Like many
>   aspects of CSS, this is a bit confusing at first.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But when i change the height 1000px to 100% in .sub-container, it disappeared. Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dLeHL/5/) what you're trying to achieve?

I change the width of the `.sub-container` in order to be in `%` like the `.main-container`.

**CSS** markup:

```
html, body { 
    height:100% 
}
.main-container { 
    height:100%; 
    background:red; 
}
.sub-container { 
    height:100%; 
    width:75%; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    background:blue; 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, if you scroll down on http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/dLeHL/ you will be noticed the red box is cut behind the blue box. I want red box flexible according to the blue box height and 100% vertically fit on the screen even blue box small or large.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set the `height` for the `.main-container` (by default it will expand to the size of the child container). By setting the height to 100% you are forcing it  to be the height of the screen and no more. So just change it to:

```
.main-container { background:red; }
```

If you need the main container to always be at least the height of the screen, use @Helstein's suggestion of setting the `min-height` to 100% while removing the `height` setting.